# Angular ng-repeat displays too many buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my controller and a nested array/object.

```
var MainController = function ($scope) {
    var test_model = nested //setup_model_groups(portfolio_repository);
    $scope.positions = test_model;

var nested = [{orchards: [{orchard_name: "North", tree_type:[{tree_type_name: "Apple",varieties: [{ name: "Fuji", number: 50 },{ name: "Granny", number: 100 }]}, {tree_type_name: "Cherry", varieties: [{ name: "Black", number: 10 },{ name: "Red", number: 75 }]}]}]}, {orchards: [{orchard_name: "South", tree_type: [{tree_type_name: "Orange", varieties:[{name: "Navel", number:35}, { name: "Tangerine", number: 60 }]}]}]}]
```

And here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>MY First Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet1.css" />
    <script src="JavaScript1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-repeat="a in positions">
        <div ng-repeat="b in a">
            <div ng-repeat="c in b">
                {{c.orchard_name}}
                <div ng-repeat="d in c">
                    <div ng-repeat="e in d">                        
                        {{e.tree_type_name}}
                        <form> <input type="submit" /></form>
                        <table ng-repeat="f in e.varieties">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th>
                                      <button>Add A New Tree Type</button>
                                  </th>
                              </tr>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        {{f.name }}
                                        <input ng-model="f.number" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem here is the button "Add a New Tree Type". It appears for every variety when I just want it to appear once for every Tree Type to the right of the tree name.

What do I need to change?

Thanks

Rye

Answer (score 0):

You need to move out table header from the last repeater.

```
                <div ng-repeat="e in d">                        
                    {{e.tree_type_name}}
                    <form> <input type="submit" /></form>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>
                                  <button>Add A New Tree Type</button>
                              </th>
                          </tr>
                        <tbody>

                            <tr ng-repeat="f in e.varieties">
                                <td>
                                    {{f.name }}
                                    <input ng-model="f.number" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Also, if you need to submit data from this table, you will need to move your `form` end tag.

Comment: @CmaStena Thanks however now I get multiple "tables" with a single  input element "Add a New Tree".

Comment: I do not see "Add a New Tree" button in the original HTML markup. Could you create jsfiddle with the sample and share it?